# How to count matching elements in a recursive XQuery function

Tags: xpath, xquery

The following code works, but now I want to specify as a parameter which occurrence of an element specified by the xpath will be affected (replaced, deleted, inserted, etc.)

```
  declare function local:replace($doc as node(), $new-content as item()*, 
    $target-path as xs:string)  {
    local:transform($doc, $new-content, $target-path, 'replace', "")
  };

  declare function local:transform($node as node(), $new-content as item()*, 
        $target-path as xs:string,  $action as xs:string, $path as xs:string) 
        as node()+ {
    if ($node instance of element() and concat($path, "/", node-name($node)) = $target-path)
    then
      if ($action = 'insert-before')
      then ($new-content, $node) 
      else

      if ($action = 'insert-after')
      then ($node, $new-content)
      else

      if ($action = 'insert-as-child')
      then element {node-name($node)}
        {
        $node/@*
        ,
        $new-content
        ,
          for $child in $node/node()
            return $child
        }
        else

        if ($action = 'replace')
        then $new-content
        else 

        if ($action = 'delete')
        then ()
        else ()
    else
        if ($node instance of element()) 
        then
            element {node-name($node)} 

            {
            $node/@* 
            ,
            for $child in $node/node()
                return 
                  local:transform($child, $new-content, $target-path,  $action, concat($path,  "/", node-name($node)))
            }
         else $node
};



let $doc :=
<fo:Test xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:books>
    <!-- These are my books --> 
    <book title='xQuery for Dummys'>
      <author>Jack Wizard</author>
      <details>    
        <pages>221</pages>
      </details>
    </book>  
    <book title='Mysteries of xQuery'>
      <author>Lost Linda</author>
      <details>
        <replace-this>Goodbye World!</replace-this>
        <pages>40</pages>
      </details>
    </book>  
  </fo:books>
</fo:Test>

(: -------- My test -------- :)
let $new-content := <replaced>Hello World!</replaced> return
local:replace($doc, $new-content, '/fo:Test/fo:books/book/details/replace-this')
```

Obviously `$global-counter = $global-counter + 1` isn't going to work.  I want to pass in the occurrence I want as another parameter like this:

```
    local:replace($doc, $new-content, '/fo:Test/fo:books/book/details/pages', 2)
```

And get this output:

```
<fo:Test xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:books>
    <!-- These are my books --> 
    <book title='xQuery for Dummys'>
      <author>Jack Wizard</author>
      <details>    
        <pages>221</pages>
      </details>
    </book>  
    <book title='Mysteries of xQuery'>
      <author>Lost Linda</author>
      <details>
        <replace-this>Goodbye World!</replace-this>
        <replaced>Hello World!</replaced>
      </details>
    </book>  
  </fo:books>
</fo:Test>
```

Instead of this unwanted result I'd get with using `local:replace($doc, $new-content, '/fo:Test/fo:books/book/details/pages')`

```
<fo:Test xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:books>
    <!-- These are my books --> 
    <book title='xQuery for Dummys'>
      <author>Jack Wizard</author>
      <details>    
        <replace-this>Goodbye World!</replace-this>
      </details>
    </book>  
    <book title='Mysteries of xQuery'>
      <author>Lost Linda</author>
      <details>
        <replace-this>Goodbye World!</replace-this>
        <replaced>Hello World!</replaced>
      </details>
    </book>  
  </fo:books>
</fo:Test>
```

Is there any way to keep count of the number of positive matches I get and add that to the condition?  I'm stumped!

Comment: In my understanding the path `/fo:Test/fo:books/book/details/pages[2]` does not select anything in your sample XML as there is no `details` element at all having a second `pages` child.

Comment: But which element is supposed to be selected with that path `/fo:Test/fo:books/book/details/pages[2]`? In your sample none. You could use e.g. `/fo:Test/fo:books/book[2]/details/pages` or `(/fo:Test/fo:books/book/details/pages)[2]`.

Comment: It selects hopefully what I want it too.  It's up to me to define the syntax of the input.  It's just a way of passing the occurrence value without making it another parameter.  But as shown in my desired output, if it weren't a recursive function and a simple xpath selection problem, we'd use `(/fo:Test/fo:books/book/details/pages)[2]`

Comment: Well, then you shouldn't call it " to pass in the occurrence I want in the xpath".

Comment: Question edited to make the occurrence value as a separate parameter to the function instead of being part of the path.  Hopefully that will add additional clarity.

Comment: I mostly use XSLT and the whole point of your `transform` function seems to be a job that XSLT can do well so perhaps, depending on your XQuery environment, you have access to an extension like http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XSLT_Module#xslt:transform or the standardized https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-transform. In that case you could write or generate XSLT code with the necessary match patterns to perform the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following provides an example similar to what you are trying to achieve, it does so by using recursion and memorising the path as it goes so that it can compare against your path that you wish to replace.

This uses XQuery 3.1, however it could be rewritten in XQuery 1.0 by encoding/decoding the map structure to/from a sequence or an in-memory XML document.

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare namespace fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format";

declare %private function local:push-element($path-stack as map(xs:integer, map(xs:QName, xs:integer)), $element as element(), $depth as xs:integer) as map(xs:integer, map(xs:QName, xs:integer)) {
    let $occurence-map := $path-stack($depth)
    return
      if(not(empty($occurence-map))) then
        let $name-occurs := $occurence-map(node-name($element))
        return
          if($name-occurs) then
            map:put($path-stack, $depth, map:put($occurence-map, node-name($element), $name-occurs + 1))
          else
             map:put($path-stack, $depth, map:put($occurence-map, node-name($element), 1))
      else
        map:put($path-stack, $depth, map { node-name($element) : 1 })

        (: TODO to reduce memory you could remove (pop) any elements from the map which have depth gt $depth :)
};

declare %private function local:children($children as node()*, $replace as xs:string, $replacement as element(), $current-path as xs:QName*, $path-stack as map(xs:integer, map(xs:QName, xs:integer))) {
  if($children)then
    let $child := $children[1]
    return
      let $new-path-stack :=
        if($child instance of element())then
          local:push-element($path-stack, $child, count($current-path) + 1)
        else
          $path-stack
      return
      (
        local:replace($child, $replace, $replacement, $current-path, $new-path-stack),
        local:children(subsequence($children, 2), $replace, $replacement, $current-path, $new-path-stack)
      )
  else()      
};

declare %private function local:get-occurence($name as xs:QName, $depth as xs:integer, $path-stack as map(xs:integer, map(xs:QName, xs:integer))) {
  $path-stack($depth)($name)
};

declare %private function local:eq-path-with-positions($current-path as xs:QName*,  $path-stack as map(xs:integer, map(xs:QName, xs:integer)), $path-with-positions as xs:string) as xs:boolean {
  let $current-path-with-positions :=
    '/' || string-join(
      for $step-qn at $depth in $current-path
      let $occurence :=  local:get-occurence($step-qn, $depth, $path-stack)
      let $occurence-predicate-str := '[' || $occurence || ']'
      return
        $step-qn || $occurence-predicate-str
      , '/'
    )
  return
    $path-with-positions eq $current-path-with-positions
};

declare %private function local:replace($node as node(), $replace as xs:string, $replacement as element(), $current-path as xs:QName*, $path-stack as map(xs:integer, map(xs:QName, xs:integer))) as node() {

    typeswitch($node)

        case document-node()
        return
              document {
                  $node/node() ! local:replace(., $replace, $replacement, $current-path, $path-stack)
              }

        case element()
        return
            let $new-path := ($current-path, node-name($node))
            let $new-path-stack :=
              if(map:size($path-stack) eq 0) then
                local:push-element($path-stack, $node, count($new-path))
              else
                $path-stack
            return 
                let $matched-for-replace := local:eq-path-with-positions($new-path, $new-path-stack, $replace)
                return
                  if($matched-for-replace)then
                    $replacement
                  else            
                    element {name($node)} {
                        $node/@*,
                        local:children($node/node(), $replace, $replacement, $new-path, $new-path-stack)
                    }

        default return $node


};

declare function local:replace($node as node(), $replace as xs:string, $replacement as element()) as node() {
    let $path-stack as map(xs:integer, map(xs:QName, xs:integer)) := map {}
    return
        local:replace($node, $replace, $replacement, (), $path-stack)
};

let $doc :=
    <fo:Test xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:books>
        <!-- These are my books --> 
        <book title='xQuery for Dummys'>
          <author>Jack Wizard</author>
          <details>    
            <pages>221</pages>
          </details>
        </book>  
        <book title='Mysteries of xQuery'>
          <author>Lost Linda</author>
          <details>
            <replace-this>Goodbye World!</replace-this>
            <pages>40</pages>
          </details>
        </book>  
      </fo:books>
    </fo:Test>
return
    local:replace($doc, '/fo:Test[1]/fo:books[1]/book[2]/details[1]/pages[1]', <replaced>Hello World!</replaced>)
```